# angularjs firebase login scope value is not available after refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have my `pseudonym` in the `$scope` and I try to access it from other views after the user has logged in, using:

however, when I refresh the page immediately after the user has successfully signed in, the `$scope` value reverts back into `{{pseudonym}}` and the parameter isn't available. How can I save this data persistently throughout the logged in session?
 Can you please provide the answer with an example?

```
app.controller("MyregisterCtrl", ["$scope", "$stateParams", "Auth", "$state", "$location", "$modal", "DatabaseRef", "$rootScope",
    function ($scope, $stateParams, Auth, $state, $location, $modal, DatabaseRef, $rootScope) {   
        $scope.user = {};
        $scope.signIn = function () {
            if (!$scope.user.email && !$scope.user.password) {
                toastr.error("Add email and password");
            } else {
                Auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword($scope.user.email, $scope.user.password)
                    .then(function(firebaseUser) {

                        var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
                        DatabaseRef.ref('/users/' + userId).once('value')
                            .then(function(snapshot) {
                                pseudonym = snapshot.val().pseudonym;
                                console.log("pseudonym: ", pseudonym);
                                $scope.pseudonym = pseudonym;
                            });
                        $state.go('app.dashboard');

                        if (!firebaseUser.emailVerified) {
                            // firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification();
                            toastr.info('Your email is NOT verified.', 'Verify email!');
                            $state.go('login.signin');
                        }
                        // $state.go('home');
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        toastr.error(error.message, error.reason, { timeOut: 10000 });
                        $scope.user = {};
                    })
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a Service to store the value and retrieve it whenever you need.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.service('mySingleton', function() {
    var username= "test";
    return {
        username : username
    };
});

function MyCtrl($scope, mySingleton) {
    $scope.username= mySingleton.username;
}

function MyCtrl2($scope, mySingleton) {
    $scope.username= mySingleton.username;
}
```

Comment: could you please tell me what part of my code in the login controller should I store in the service? Should I completely remove it from login controller and put it in service? or both?

Comment: wait let me show, check this sample https://plnkr.co/edit/9FUSD4LyETI4itmfBtwK?p=preview

Comment: the example is a bit difficult to relate to my original controller. Is it possible to give an adapted response to my controller?

Comment: what you have done is right here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058330/angularjs-firebase-user-auth-service-not-communicating-with-the-views mark as answer if it has helped