# angularjs firebase user auth service not communicating with the views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase-authentication, angularjs-service

I have a service which passes on the parameter `pseudonym`  to the evironment. I call on this `pseudonym` in my views, but it doesn't appear at all.
How can I fix this to display the value in my views?

**MyUser service**:

```
app.service('MyUser', ['DatabaseRef', 'firebase', function(DatabaseRef, firebase) {
    var pseudonym ="";
    var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

    return {
        pseudonym: function() {
            DatabaseRef.ref('/users/' + userId).once('value')
                .then(function (snapshot) {
                    pseudonym = snapshot.val().pseudonym;
                    console.log("pseudony: ", pseudonym);
                    return pseudonym;
                });

        }
    }
}]);
```

***in my console, I see the value for the `pseudonym`. but not in my view html using {{pseudonym}}***
and here is the example view controller:

```
app.controller('ExampleCtrl', ["MyUser",
    function (MyUser) {
     $scope.pseudonym = MyUser.pseudonym();
}]);
```

Comment: put a console.log and check if you can see the variable

Comment: @Sajeetharan I put a console log in my view controller and it gives me undefined! but it gives the right value in the console log inside the service.

Comment: Change the function name other than pseudonym

Comment: @Sajeetharan the function name in the service only? `newpseudonym: function() {...` for example? and in the view controller `MyUser.newpseudonym();` ?

Comment: yeah, nothing pops up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the promise created by the `.then` method:

```
app.service('MyUser', ['DatabaseRef', 'firebase', function(DatabaseRef, firebase) {
    //var pseudonym ="";
    var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

    return {
        getUserName: function() {
            //return promise
            return (
                DatabaseRef.ref('/users/' + userId).once('value')
                    .then(function onSuccess(snapshot) {
                        let pseudonym = snapshot.val().pseudonym;
                        console.log("pseudony: ", pseudonym);
                        return pseudonym;
                })
            );
        }
    }
}]);
```

Then extract the value from that promise:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('loginController',['$scope', 'MyUser',function($scope, MyUser)
{
    let promise = MyUser.getUserName();
    //Extract data from promise
    promise.then( function onSuccess(pseudonym) {
        $scope.pseudonym  = pseudonym;
        console.log($scope.pseudonym);
    });
}]);
```

The `.then` method of an object always returns a promise derived from the value (or promise) returned by the handler function furnished as an argument to that `.then` method.